# Xamarin iOS How to Zoom on UIView and UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, xamarin, pinchzoom

I am developping an iPad app using Xamaring that has several views in the storyboard (`UIView` and `UITableView`). My users want to zoom on usual pages (as they are used to in a web browser or so).

So, having read about `UIScrollView`, I simply tried to put my page views embedded within a `UIScrollView`, but I can neither scroll nor pinch-zoom: nothing happens.

As for the setup: in the StoryBoard, I add a `UIScrollView` to the `UIViewController` which fills the parent. I then add content to the `UIScrollView`, which I want to be zoomable (e.g. for people with poor sight).

So the question is quite simple: how can I get a view fitting within its original parent but that can be zoomed onto ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesent work"? Does it scroll at all, but not zoom? How have you set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done this myself, so I dont know if this is all it takes. But have you added the max- and min-scroll and all that?

```
scrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3f;
scrollView.MinimumZoomScale = .1f;
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { return     imageView; };
```

(in your case i guess it needs to return the view);

If that doesent do the trick, take a look at "Scrolling and zooming a view hierarchy on this page: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: Thanks DyreVaa!
I forgot to set the part
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { return     myMainUIView; }; It works perfectly fine now!

Comment: Good stuff! Im sure will be a lot of issues with supporting that far back. A lot of changes have been made to the different controls since then.

Comment: I removed my note: it actually DOES work even with iOS 5.1.1 !